# How can I detect browser and OS of user and use this to dynamically modify my MySQL database query from a PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, session, amfphp, browser-detection

I need to be able to run a mysql query and omit certain results if the user is using a certain browser on a certain OS. My database query takes place from an AMFPHP service and I have a javascript browserDetect script that I can use to get user browser and OS.

Ideally I want to run the browserDetect script when the user arrives at my page and then store this in the PHP session variables but I cannot see how to pass the javascript vars to the PHP session. This would allow my database query script to look up the session and modify the query accordingly. I also tried to include the browser detect script in the AMFPHP script but this did not work - I realise that this a serverside vs client side problem.

What other solutions would work for me?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not accomplish that with PHP only? PHP is also capable of fetching browser and os...
`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains browser and os...

Answer (score 2):

As @thedom said, just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in PHP. Your user agent (Unless modified by the user) will contain the browser, browser version and os.
Here's mine:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.612.1 Safari/534.15
```

BUT if you want to use javascript, you'll have to do something similar to what I did to implement ajax logins.

I basically put this at the top of the script (login.php)

```
session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

And this in the page the javascript will be run from to detect session (index.php)

```
$sessionid = ($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) ? $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] : $_GET['PHPSESSID'];
<script type="text/javascript">var session = "$sessionid";</script>
```

And then I post to the other script (login.php) (To log you in via ajax in this case)

```
$.post("ajax/login.php",PHPSESSID=" + session);
```

Using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the results from browserDetect javascript to javascript cookie, and PHP is able to read cookie from that

details : [How to read Javascript cookie with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368097/how-to-read-javascript-cookie-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to let the javascript make an ajax request containing OS/Browser, yet the better way might be to parse the user agent.